# Separar a soma com um " " em c#

Tags: c#, array

Quero poder definir os valores do vetor sem  dae uma quebra de linha.
quero que fique dessa forma: 255 2255 25

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BigSum
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            long n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long[] BigSum = new long[n];


            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                BigSum[i] = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            long sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                sum += BigSum[i];

            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É só ler a entrada do usuário, fazer a quebra por espaço(s) e depois converter cada item quebrado em número...

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Se for oque voce quer pode ser assim:

Console.WriteLine(" "+ sum +" ");

Comment: O autor da pergunta quer saber como ler os vários valores para um vetor em uma única chamada de `Console.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mas, até lá, escreva apenas respostas que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/445911)